# ReactJS TypeScript render prop hide parameter

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript, react-tsx

How can I disable access to injected parameter in `render prop`, if a specific prop is not set to component that renders the render prop.

```
interface Test {
    test: string
}

interface ComponentProps {
    someProp?: Test,
    children: (params: {param1: boolean, param2: string}) => ReactElement
}

const Component = ({someProp, children}: ComponentProps) => {
    return children({
        param1: false,
        param2: 'test'
    })
}
```

Here how to disable `param2` to be used if someProp is not provided to Component, with TypeScript.
This should be invalid:

```
const instance = <Component>
    {
        ({param1, param2}) => <div>{param2}</div>
    }
</Component>
```

And those valid:

```
        // someProp is not set, so I can not use param2
       <Component>
            {
                ({param1}) => <div>static text</div>
            }
        </Component>

  
     // someProp is set, so I can use param2
     <Component someProp={{test: 'demo'}}>
            {
                ({param1, param2}) => <div>{param2}</div>
            }
    </Component>
```

I want to conditionally exclude param2 from **the type**, not from the value

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you can conditionally render the children:

```
const Component = ({someProp, children}: ComponentProps) => {
    return !!someProp ? children({
        param1: false
    }) : children({
        param1: false,
        param2: 'test'
    })
}
```

Comment: What about the type? I can still access it with TypeScript. Just JS gives it as undefined

Comment: Typescript is not intended to be a runtime type checker. Although there are some libraries which will allow you to do runtime type checking. I haven't used one, therefore I can't give a suggestion but I am sure you will be able to find good resources.

Comment: I do not want a runtime type checker. I want it to throw me an error while passing the children prop if I try to destructure params and use param2. Your solution will allow me to use it but will throw a runtime error. I want to conditionally exclude param2 from the type, not from the value